Bulk API 2.0 Create Job - Returns 200 (OK) with a truncated body
I am trying to create a batch BULK API 2.0. After connecting to the trail ground and authorizing it with a new access toke,  I sent the below body in POST request:
{

"operation" : "insert",
"object" : "Account",
"contentType" : "CSV",
"lineEnding": CRLF

}


Setting lineEnding to either LF or CRLF has no effect on this. As I
am from Windows OS and using notepad as my text editor , CRLF is the
natural choice here.

In the settings tab, Follow Authorization header is enabled.


This returns a status 200, with  below response:
{
   "done": true,
   "nextRecordsUrl": null,
   "records": []
}

             

The response should be much larger with job Id, Status and content URL :
{
    "id": "750...",
    "operation": "insert",
    "object": "Account",
    "createdById": "005...",
    "createdDate": "<datetime>",
    "systemModstamp": "<datetime>",
    "state": "Open",
    "concurrencyMode": "Parallel",
    "contentType": "CSV",
    "apiVersion": 58,
    "contentUrl": "services/data/v58.0/jobs/ingest/750.../batches",
    "lineEnding": "LF",
    "columnDelimiter": "COMMA"
}

